# トークン方式にログインする方法とは？

Tags: java

個人的な興味で、
トークンを用いているホームページに
ログインしてスクレイピングしてみたいと思って、
書いてみたのですが、そもそもログインからしてうまく行きません。
原因は何なのか出来る限り自分でも調べたのですが、よくわかりません。

以下コードですが、

値として、data[_Token][key]とdata[_Token][fields]はページを手動検索して取得。
ほかは知っているので、４つの値をそれぞれ入力。といった感じです。
値はクロームの機能で調べてみましたが、あってるのかはよくわかりません。

結果は、ログイン失敗ページにリダイレクトされた旨のHTML内容が返ってきます。

まだJAVA歴が数ヶ月しかなく、
WEB関連部分は知識がかなり不足している状態なので、
コードに致命的に間違っている部分があったかもしれません……。
ご教示いただけると助かります。

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
    String url = "https://www.lancers.jp/user/login";
    String user = "https://www.lancers.jp/mypage";
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    RequestConfig reqconf = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(true)
            .setRedirectsEnabled(true)
            .build();
    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    headers.add(new BasicHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT));
    headers.add(new BasicHeader("Accept-Charset","utf-8"));
    headers.add(new BasicHeader("Accept-Language","ja, en;q=0.8"));
    headers.add(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(reqconf)
            .setDefaultHeaders(headers)
            .build();

    CloseableHttpResponse loginpage = client.execute(get);
    String loginpageHTML = EntityUtils.toString(loginpage.getEntity(),"UTF-8");
    //JsoupとかでもTokenのみパースは無理ぽかったので、手動で検索‥
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?is)value=\"(.+?)\""); 
    Matcher m = p.matcher(loginpageHTML);
    //トークンを探す。
    String[] TokenArray = new String[6];

    int i= 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        TokenArray[i]=m.group((1));
        i++;
    }
    //TokenArray[1]　TokenArray[5]
    //1はkey,5はfields. これをPOST送信に含めてみることにする。

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[_Token][key]",TokenArray[1]));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[User][email]","自分のID"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[User][password]","自分のPASS"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[User][auto_login]","0"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[User][referer]","http://www.lancers.jp/"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[_Token][fields]",TokenArray[5]));

    post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    post.setHeader("Referer", user);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    String html="";
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    try{
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    html=EntityUtils.toString(entity,"UTF-8");
    EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    }finally{
        response.close();
    }

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    System.out.println(doc);


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

ソースコードを確認しました。とりあえずは動いているようですね。  
こういうことをやるときはブラウザで一度ログインして、ブラウザの開発者モードからリクエストヘッダを眺めてみるといいです。ただ、サーバ側がAPIを提供しているわけではないと思うので、若干リバースエンジニアリングのようになってしまいます。サーバ側がそのようなAPIを公開しているWebサービスで練習したほうがよいのではないかと思います。あと、トークン方式という言葉は初めて聞いたのですが独自用語でしょうか。

## ログインの流れ

さて、ログから、ログインの流れは以下のようにすればよいとわかります。

```
1. POST  https://www.lancers.jp/user/login

   *** Formを送信してクッキーCakeCookie[User]をもらう ***

   [送信するForm]
   data[_Token][key]:トークン
   data[User][email]:メールアドレス
   data[User][password]:パスワード
   data[User][auto_login]:よくわからん値
   data[User][referer]:リファラ
   submit:ログインする　（送信ボタンの値：おそらく任意）
   data[_Token][fields]: URLエンコードされたトークン

   [送信するクッキー]
   CakeCookie[LANCERS_C]
   CakeCookie[CLIENT]
   CakeCookie[arcmnd]

   [受信できるクッキー]
   CakeCookie[User]

2. GET   http://www.lancers.jp/mypage

   *** CakeCookie[Users]をリクエストヘッダに含めてGET、mypageの場所を取得 ***

   [受信できるヘッダ]
   Location:https://www.lancers.jp/mypage?[0-9]{10}&

3. GET   https://www.lancers.jp/mypage?[0-9]{10}&

   *** HTTPSでmypageにログイン ***
```

## 1. POST /user/login

### リクエスト概要

```
Remote Address:52.68.161.170:443
Request URL:https://www.lancers.jp/user/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
```

### リクエストヘッダ

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:{*** POSTするコンテンツの長さ ***}
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: {*** クッキーいろいろ ***}
Host:www.lancers.jp
Origin:https://www.lancers.jp
Referer:https://www.lancers.jp/user/login?{*** ユーザの固有ID(数字) ***}&
User-Agent: {*** ここはなんでもいい ***}
```

### フォーム値

```
_method:POST
data[_Token][key]:token_token_token_token_token...
data[User][email]:nanashi_no_gonbei@example.com
data[User][password]:this_is_password
data[User][auto_login]:0  // ログ上は0とも1とも設定されていて
data[User][auto_login]:1  // あまり意味のないものと思われる
data[User][referer]:http://www.lancers.jp/
submit:ログインする
data[_Token][fields]: {*** URLエンコードされたトークン ***}
```

### レスポンスヘッダ

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 22 Jun 2015 01:02:31 GMT
Location:http://www.lancers.jp/mypage
P3P:CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:CakeCookie[User]     
Set-Cookie:CakeCookie[LANCERS_C]
Set-Cookie:CakeCookie[CLIENT]   
Set-Cookie:CakeCookie[arcmnd]
```

## 2. GET /mypage

mypageの実際の場所をもらう。ブラウザの場合Locationが含まれていれば自動でリダイレクトされる気がする。

### レスポンスヘッダ

```
Location:https://www.lancers.jp/mypage?[0-9]{10}&
```

## 3. GET /mypage?[0-9]{10}&

HTTPSでリクエスト、これにて完了

Comment: はい、クロームの機能で眺めていましたが、
POST送信での値くらいしかよく理解できませんでした。

トークン方式というのは、単にこのホームページで使用してるものを指していったものです。特に公式用語とかではないと思います。

クッキーの部分は見つけられなかったか、注意深くみていなかったかもしれません。もういちどクッキーの方も参考に挑戦してみます。

ありがとうございました。